# Creating a form trigger from a google apps script web app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've got a web app (deployed from a stand-alone script) that creates a new GSheet and GForm and then links the form to the sheet to store the responses.

What I would like to do is create an "on form submit" trigger from within the web app that fires on a form submission; get the whole thing working with one-click on the web app. I can create the trigger in the web app script but nothing happens on form submission, I have to create it from the script contained in either the new sheet or form for that - two clicks!

Would one-click be possible??

I could do this with an add-on but they aren't allowed on this particular domain.

[Here's the question on the GAS+ forum](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndrewRoberts1/posts/9RCw28UAL5m?cfem=1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you need, but I think this is what you want:

```
function onSubmitTrigger(){
 //psuedocode(ish)
       /*
1.Get range of values
2.Find last submitted value
3.Pass value to function "onSubmit"

Or just run a function and skip passing a value
        */        
}
  function onSubmit(e) {
     //Run whatever you need to run
 }
```

You can set the trigger within the actual service:
Click on the clock icon:
[image: Clock Icon]

Then go ahead and set up a new trigger:
[image: Set up]

Select the function `onSubmitTrigger()` and you can set it up to run as the form is submitted:
[image: Set-Up]

BTW: you can map a image on the spreadsheet to run a function if that is easier for you..

Comment: Actually, he is trying to record the event when the web app form is submitted, these triggers that you mentioned won't help in this scenario.